# React route couldn't render component with passing data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am still learning react by myself. Here I tried to use sub-route to render a component with props data, but it didn't work. Here is my code that has been simplified:

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Building from "../components/listingPage/buildingWeb";

class App extends Component {

 render() {
   return (
    <Router className="App">
    <div>
      <nav className="navbar navbar-default">
        <div className="container-fluid">
          <Link to="/building-web">Building Web</Link>           
        </div>
      </nav>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/building-web" component={Building} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
    </Router>
    );
   }
  }

export default App;
```

**BuildingWeb.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ListPage from "../../common/listPage";
import ArticleApi from "../../api/articleApi";
import SingleArticle from "./singleArticlepage";
import { Link, Route } from "react-router-dom";
// data sample
  const productsData = [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "NIKE Liteforce Blue Sneakers",
        description: "test",
        status: "Available"
       }
      ];

class Building extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      products: productsData
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
  <div className="nav-text">
    <h1>Coding fun page</h1>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        {this.state.products.map(product => (
          <tr key={product.id}>
            <td>
              <Link to={`${this.props.match.url}/${product.id}`}>
                {product.name}
              </Link>
            </td>
          </tr>
        ))}
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <Route
      path={`${this.props.match.url}/:productId`}
      // this part doesn't work
      render={props => <SingleArticle data={this.state.products} {...props} />}
    />
  </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Building;
```

**singleArticlepage.js**

```
import React from "react";

const SingleArticle = ({ match, data }) => {
  var product = data.find(p => p.id === Number(match.params.productId));
  var productData;

  if (product)
    productData = (
      <div>
        <h3> {product.name} </h3>
        <p>{product.description}</p>
        <hr />
        <h4>{product.status}</h4>{" "}
      </div>
    );
  else productData = <h2> Sorry. Product doesnt exist </h2>;

  return (
    <div>
      <div>{productData}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SingleArticle;
```

When I click /building-web, it can render the Building component, but when I click /building-web/1, it can't get the singleArticle component here. Is it because path props not right?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is not passing data here. Just remove the exact prop from your /building-web Route definition.

```
<Route path="/building-web" component={Building} />
```

But, with this setup your main Building component will always be rendered above the SingleArticle component . If you want to show only SingleArticle you need something like this in your Building component:

```
  <div className="nav-text">
    <Route
      exact
      path="/building-web"
      component={() => (
        <div>
          <h1>Coding fun page</h1>
          <table>
            <tbody>
              {this.state.products.map( product => (
                <tr key={product.id}>
                  <td>
                    <Link to={`${ this.props.match.url }/${ product.id }`}>
                      {product.name}
                    </Link>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              ) )}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      )}
    />
    <Route
      path={`${ this.props.match.url }/:productId`}
      // this part doesn't work
      render={props => <SingleArticle data={this.state.products} {...props} />}
    />
  </div>
```

I don't know any other easy way to do that. If possible I want to learn, too :)

Comment: thanks for your solution. Actually I am learning the nested route via this example: https://www.sitepoint.com/react-router-v4-complete-guide/, however I follow their example did some modification on my code then it doesn't work at all.

Comment: You are welcome. If you want regular nested routes then just drop the `exact` prop from your definition. You don't need my second suggestion. And if my answer is sufficient for your needs you may consider accepting it.